Slice a geotiff file by latitude
I have a geotiff file. I use python to read it and plot it
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show


src = rasterio.read('myfile.tif')
data = src.read(1)

f,ax=plt.subplots()
show(data, transform=src.transform, ax=ax)


I would like to make a slice and from 7.5e6 to 5e6, from 5e6 to 2.5e6...from -5.0e6 to -7.5e6 to and mask the file for each slice.
